# modular exponentiation large power mod composite number

Tags: number-theory

$$x^{11} \equiv 12 \pmod{143}$$

How to solve this without any sophisticated methods?
$$x^{11} \equiv 12 \pmod{143}$$

$${x^{120}}\equiv 12^{10}\pmod{143} $$

Is this correct knowing that x could divide 143?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $x$ cannot divide $143$, because $12$ and $143$ are coprime, hence $12$ is a unit mod. $143$.

Comment: Are the equations separate equations?

Comment: It was not so clear sorry , I just edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $143=11\cdot13,$ $$x^{11}\equiv12\pmod{143}$$

$\implies(i)x^{11}\equiv12\pmod{11}\equiv1$

But by Fermat's little theorem, $x^{11-1}\equiv1\pmod{11}\implies x\equiv1\pmod{11}\ \ \ \ (1)$

and $(ii)x^{11}\equiv12\pmod{13}\equiv-1,$

Now $12x\equiv x^{12}\equiv1\pmod{13}$ by Fermat's little theorem

$\implies 1\equiv12x\equiv-x\iff \equiv-1\pmod{13}\ \ \ \ (2)$

Using Chinese remainder theorem/by observation, $$x\equiv12\pmod{\text{lcm}(11,13)}$$

Comment: Thanks ! I need to learn the Chinese remainder theorem but in this case I see why the answer must be 12 .

Answer (score 1):

$x^{11}\equiv12\pmod{143}\implies x^{22}\equiv1\pmod{143}$, as $12^2=1\pmod{143}$

Fermat's little theorem gives:

$$x^{\varphi(143)}=x^{120}=1\pmod{143}\implies 1^6=(x^{22})^6=x^{132}\equiv x^{12}\pmod{143}$$

So, $x^{11}=12$ and $x^{12}=1$.Noting that $x^{12}$ is an invertible element of $\mathbb{Z}_{143}$, we know that $x$ must also be invertible. We thus divide the two equations and see that $x$ must be the inverse of $12\pmod{143}$ - which is $12$.

We thus have that $x=12$ is our only solution to this equation.

Comment: No worries! Note that in the edit to your question, the exponentiation is correct or incorrect depending on how you bracket - for example, $2^{2^3}=256, (2^2)^3=64$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
$$
x^{11\cdot11}=x^{\varphi(143)+1}\equiv x\pmod{143}
$$
Furthermore, note that $12^2\equiv1\pmod{143}$.